# How to connect the middle-top of bars in barplot with a line, using seaborn or matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

```
myDict = {'a':[3,13,18,16,19,9,13,15,0,2],\
      'b':[23,14,18,24,19,9,14,13,21,22],\
      'c':[38,17,12,15,39,38,23,19,16,16]}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(myDict)
df_melted = df.melt(value_vars=['a','b','c'])

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x='variable',y='value',data=df_melted,capsize=0.1,ax=ax1,order=['b','a','c'])
plt.
plt.show()
plt.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `lineplot` but first, you need to keep the same order because `lineplot` does not have the `order` argument as `barplot`. The steps are:

1. Create a copy of the dataframe
2. Set `variable` to be categorical with the `order` of `['b','a','c']`
3. lineplot in the same ax

The code would be:

```
order = ['b', 'a', 'c']
df_2 = df_melted.copy()
df_2['variable'] = pd.Categorical(df_2['variable'], order)
df_2.sort_values('variable', inplace=True)

#plot
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x='variable', y='value', data=df_melted, capsize=0.1, ax=ax1,
            order=order)
sns.lineplot(x='variable', y='value', data=df_2,
             ax=ax1, color='r', marker='+', linewidth=5, ci=None)
plt.show()
```

That will produce:

[image]

Comment: Great buddy, that's exactly what I've been trying to do. Thank you so much for your time.